# How can I print in log the number of tests running as part of one group in TestNG?

Tags: selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, testng

I need to print this before actual execution of tests start. Anyways, we get the count at last of execution.

Say for example if my testng.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="Suite1">
   <test name="test1">

   <groups>
      <run>
      <include name="functest" />
      </run>
   </groups>

   <classes>
      <class name="GroupTestExample" />
   </classes>

   </test>
</suite>
```

And there are 10 methods in class GroupTestExample which comes under group functest, it should print 10 in log as soon as it starts running.

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom Listener which extends the `org.testng.TestListenerAdapter`. After that override the following method:

```
public class MyCustomListener extends TestListenerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void onStart(ITestContext testContext) {
    super.onStart(testContext);
    System.out.println("Number of Test Methods: " + testContext.getAllTestMethods().length);
  }

}
```

You can add your custom listener by using `@Listeners` annotation on your main class of your test, like

```
@Listeners({MyCustomListener.class})
public class MyMainTestClass { ... }
```

You can find more information in TestNG doc:

> TestNG Listeners -
>   http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-listeners